# Unable to configuring Apache-SQOOP in windows machine

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to confugure `Apache-SQOOP` in my system.
But getting below error.
May I know what is the root cause for below.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is clearly indicating that you have not a setup environment variable. go to system properties and add HBASE_HOME etc by pointing right folder location and then it will work. Since sqoop also support hive tables which further has dependencies on other Hadoop ecosystem projects, it needs support tools and libraries.

I would rather suggest using the **Cloudera** or **Hortonworks** distribution to avoid such configurations.

You can check environment variables by running set command

```
c:\> set
```

[image: windows 8 environment varialbes.]